# Form in ReactStrap Modal setting state

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

Im trying to show a modal with a form to a new note.
I'm passing JSX which contains a form to a modal, the onChange method of the input fires but does not update the state. I see the event firing up with the console.log and the values of name and value, but the state doesn't update. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Modal.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from "reactstrap";

export default function MyModal(props) {
  return (
    <Modal isOpen={props.isOpen}>
      <ModalHeader>{props.modalTitle}</ModalHeader>
      <ModalBody>{props.modalBody}</ModalBody>
      <ModalFooter>
        <Button color="primary" onClick={props.modalAction}>
          Yes
        </Button>{" "}
        <Button color="secondary" onClick={props.handleModal}>
          Cancel
        </Button>
      </ModalFooter>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

LeadView.js

```
export class LeadView extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      result: '',
      message: '',
      note: '',
      modal: false,
      modalTitle: '',
      modalBody: '',
      modalAction: '',
    }
  }
  handleChange = event => {
    console.log('name', event.target.name)
    console.log('value', event.target.value)

    const { name, value } = event.target
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    })
  }

  handleModalForNote = () => {
    this.setState({
      modal: !this.state.modal,
      modalTitle: 'New Note',
      modalBody: (
        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            name="note"
            value={this.state.note}
          />
        </div>
      ),
      modalAction: this.handleCallClick,
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <MyModal
          handleModal={this.handleModalClose}
          modalAction={this.state.modalAction}
          isOpen={this.state.modal}
          modalBody={this.state.modalBody}
          modalTitle={this.state.modalTitle}
          modalOptions={this.state.modalOptions}
        />
        <button onClick={this.handleModalForNote} className="btn btn-primary">
          Write Note
        </button>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you give the function handleChange to the input you are passing only the function itself. Then when you give that JSX to the Modal, it is being executed with the idea that whatever code it's performing should be performed in the Modal Component. What you need to do is pass the current context as well by doing

```
onChange={this.handleChange .bind(this)}
```

This binds the 'context' of your component to the function so that now wherever it is called, it will be executed in the context of your LeadView component.

You should keep this in mind for the other places where you are passing functions as well.

Comment: Even though the function does run on change? I can see the name and value in the console log when I type something, it just doesn't update the state. I tried adding .bind(this) as well but that didn't work